# cxf rest multiple endpoints

Tags: spring, rest, cxf

I have generated the java classes from a wadl file with cxf. There are 3 resources definded an so 3 service classes with @PATH annotation are created. Now I want to publish them to the same url but I'm not sure how to achieve this.
Here are the snippets of the classes and wadl. The last part shows the beans.xml - At this point this is the only way I know how to publish the endpoints. Is there anothher way and how can I publish these 3 classes to the base url "/" and then they should match to the paths related to the annotations. Maybe a wrapper class for all but I'm not sure?

classes

```
    @Path("status")
    public class Status {
    ...
    @Path("status/{id}")
    public class StatusId {
    ...
    @Path("counters")
    public class Counters{
    ...
```

wadl

```
<resources base="http:localhost:8080/rest">
    <resource path="status/{id}" id="status">
      <method name="GET" id="getStatusById">
      ...
    <resource path="status" id="status">
      <method name="GET" id="getStatusByQueryParam">
        ...
    </resource>
    <resource path="counters" id="counters">
      <method name="PUT" id="putCounters">
        ...
```

beans.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

      <!-- do not use import statements if CXFServlet init parameters link to this beans.xml -->

      <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
      <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

      <jaxrs:server id="statusService" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
          <ref bean="status" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      </jaxrs:server>

    <!-- causes error
    <jaxrs:server id="statusServiceId" address="/">  
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
          <ref bean="statusId" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      </jaxrs:server>


    <jaxrs:server id="counterServiceId" address="/">  
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
          <ref bean="counters" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      </jaxrs:server>
   --> 

      <bean id="status" class="package.Status"/>
      <bean id="statusId" class="package.StatusId"/>
      <bean id="counters" class="package.Counters"/>

    </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

for geting multiple endpoints your
**beans.xml** should be looks like bellow

```
<jaxrs:server id="statusService" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
          <ref bean="status" />
          <ref bean="statusId" />
          <ref bean="counters" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      </jaxrs:server>
```